# Material UI - Type 'string' is not assignable to type Icon

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm coding a component that will return the icon corresponding to the passed prop as follows (simplified version of my app):

```js
import * as icons from "@mui/icons-material";

interface IGenericIconProps {
  iconName: keyof typeof icons;
}

export const GenericIcon = ({ iconName }: IGenericIconProps): JSX.Element => {
  const Icon = icons[iconName];
  return <Icon />;
};
```

```js
import GenericIcon from './GenericIcon';

interface IUseGenericIconProps {
  randomIcon: string; // the error goes away if I change this to 'any'
}

const UseGenericIcon = ({randomIcon}: IUseGenericIconProps): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <GenericIcon iconName={randomIcon}/>
  )
}
```

Then in another file I have

```js
import UseGenericIcon from './UseGenericIcon';

enum MyIcons {
  Task = "TaskOutlined",
  Reminder = "AlarmOutlinedIcon",
  Other = "AnnouncementOutlinedIcon",
}

const Calendar = () => {
  return (
    <UseGenericIcon randomIcon={MyIcons.Task}/>
  )
}
```

This ends up throwing an Typescript error:

```js
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"Abc" | "AbcOutlined" | "AbcRounded" | "AbcSharp" | "AbcTwoTone" | "AcUnit" | "AcUnitOutlined" | "AcUnitRounded" | "AcUnitSharp" | "AcUnitTwoTone" | "AccessAlarm" | "AccessAlarmOutlined" | ... 9875 more ... | "ZoomOutTwoTone"'.ts(2322)
```

As noted, I can change the type from `string` to `any` and it will work, but I would like to know how can I fix this type error for future use. They both seem to be strings to me.

I got the implementation idea from
[Rendering Material-UI icons from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64724027/rendering-material-ui-icons-from-an-array)

Answer (score 1):

In `IGenericIconProps` you specify that an `iconName` must be of type `keyof typeof icons`. This type is stricter than just `string`; it's looking for a specific set of string literals that are the keys of the `icons` object. By then having `randomIcon: string` in `IUseGenericIconProps`, you've relaxed the type to be any string and so Typescript rightfully complains. Changing it to `any` simply removes all type safety. Why not export that type and use it everywhere instead?

```js
import * as icons from "@mui/icons-material";

export type IconNames = keyof typeof icons // use this in other components

interface IGenericIconProps {
  iconName: IconNames;
}

export const GenericIcon = ({ iconName }: IGenericIconProps): JSX.Element => {
  const Icon = icons[iconName];
  return <Icon />;
};
```

Comment: Be careful who is using it, It will blot your code. It will import all the SVGs to your code!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I ended up fixing it like this:

```
import React, { FC } from 'react'
import * as Icons from '@mui/icons-material'

type IconNames = keyof typeof Icons
type CustomIconProps = {
  iconName: IconNames
}

export const IconComponent: FC<CustomIconProps> = ({
  iconName,
}) => {
  const Icon = Icons[iconName]
  return <Icon />
}
```

Not exactly like your code but it might be help-full