# Rendering Ant Design icons from an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Background info:

I'm using `react` and `Ant Design`.

To keep the code clean, I populate menu items from a const array, like so:

```
const menuItems = [
  { label: "Home", path: "/home" },
  { label: "Accounts", path: "/accounts" },
  { label: "Organizations", path: "/organizations" },
];
```

Each item in the array is an object containing a label and a redirect path. I map over the items when rendering. Very basic.

**Problem:**

I would like to include an `antd` icon component in the `menuItems` array so the icon can be rendered next to the label. But I can't find a way to reference the icons by a name string

My problem is like this problem but is ant design
[Rendering Material-UI icons from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64724027/rendering-material-ui-icons-from-an-array)

Any suggestions on how to do this? Thanks

Comment: you can have the icon component in your array objects as well

Comment: @cmgchess I just had a problem with this way
if "const menuItems" is in another component, then when importing into the component you want to use "const menuItems" it will get an error

=> "Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined"

Comment: if it is in a different component maybe try passing it down as a prop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can modify your menuItems to something like this:

```
 const menuItems = [
    { label: "Home", path: "/home", icon: <span class="custom-icon" /> },
    {
      label: "Accounts",
      path: "/accounts",
      icon: <span class="custom-icon" />
    },
    {
      label: "Organizations",
      path: "/organizations",
      icon: <span class="custom-icon" />
    }
  ];
```

and instead of using `span` with the class of `custom-icon` you can use any Icon you desire and then render it accordingly

Comment: thanks but I just had a problem with this way
if "const menuItems" is in another component, then when importing into the component you want to use "const menuItems" it will get an error

=> "Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined"

Comment: @hieptran That's because you're using `jsx` and your react version is less than `17`, you can fix this by adding `import React from 'react'` at the top of the file where `const menuItems` is used

Comment: thanks but It still can't load the icon and gives a new error and and I have fixed it with these methods but it still doesn't work (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42813342/react-createelement-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string)

there is an error
=> "react.development.js:315 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports."

Comment: @hieptran add all the code in codesandbox.io and create a reproducible example of your problem so I could understand what your trying to achieve